# What REST method should be used to implement a simple inter-process communication?

Tags: rest, http, post, ipc, communication

This is more a theorical question than a practical one.

We have a backend application that uploads csv files to a frontend application, then and only then the backend sends an empty POST request to tell the frontend to start to process those files to update its database.

For this question it doesn't matter if this is a good design (I think it isn't), what are those files, and what database is: I am only want to know better about the REST "sintax".

I'm referring to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URI_and_HTTP_methods) and [restfulapi.net](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/#summary), but I'm not convinced about any alternative, because:

- GET: Request sender doesn't receive data;
- POST (the currently used): Request sender doesn't want to insert data *that are on the request body* (just data from external files, if existent. Also they can be insert/update/delete);
- PUT: Sounds good, but again, data are *not* on the request body;
- PATCH: Sounds best, but data are *not* on the body (Also, I am wrong or is it deprecated/unused?);
- DELETE: Doesn't always need to delete.

I know it is habit to use POST requests to let machines yell "*go!*" to each other, but I never thought it was right.
What do you think - in theory - would be the proper method?

Answer (score 1):

The actual reference for the semantics of the HTTP methods is the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) and not the ones you referenced in your question.

---

`POST` is a *catch all* method and requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics.

> [**4.3.3.  POST**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
>
> The `POST` method requests that the target resource process the
> representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's
> own specific semantics.  For example, `POST` is used for the following
> functions (among others):
>
> - Providing a block of data, such as the fields entered into an HTML
>   form, to a data-handling process;
> - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list,
>   blog, or similar group of articles;
> - Creating a new resource that has yet to be identified by the
>   origin server; and
> - Appending data to a resource's existing representation(s).
>
> [...]
>
> Responses to `POST` requests are only cacheable when they include
> explicit freshness information. However, `POST` caching is not widely implemented.

Answer (score 1):

In these scenarios, the receiving application knows where the CSV files will be and monitors that location. When it finds one, it processes it and then deletes or archives it. The application will likely have its own criteria for considering itself ready to process, e.g. time of day, size of file etc.

If the data load on the front end takes a long time you could "partition" the updates based on "importance". How you define importance would be up to your business rules. You could then `POST` a list of CSV filenames/locations to the front end. The list would be ordered by importance. The front end could then update its database based on that importance. Scheduling less important data for a more appropriate time of day.

If the backend knows the difference between new users and updated users you could use `PUT` and `POST`. The front end could assign higher priority to `PUT` requests as they relate to new users, perhaps assigning lower priority and staggered syncing for CSV filenames in `POST` requests.

Comment: You are very correct and I like your answer, but what actually happens in my system is the synchronization of two different databases (backend relational and frontend graph-based) in pseudo-real time. Problem is that a dataload by frontend is really time consuming (again, bad design of the software but sadly it's not up to me) so it must be triggered as few times as possible.

Comment: sounds like the trigger frequency is the main issue rather than how the front end knows when to update its database from the csv files. Can the data be partitioned based on importance? e.g. a user's email changing is more important than some other aspect of the changed data

Comment: added some ideas on PUT/POST

Comment: Seen the update and it is useful. However the design of the system is out of my power and beyond the scope of the original question...